# Unable to open SharePoint documents in Chrome

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, document-library

In Internet Explorer and Firefox, I can open Sharepoint documents. But in Chrome, it gives me an error. 
How can I directly open Sharepoint files in Chrome like I do in Internet Explorer?
[image]

Comment: what is the sharepoint version?

Comment: I am using SharePoint Server 2013, I resolved that by adding IE Tab extension to Google Chrome! But Is there another way to resolve that ? Thanks.